# Issue in executing command containing single quote using Plink

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd, plink

I am using `plink.exe` from `cmd` in Windows 10, to ssh to Ubuntu 16.04. In there, I am running MATLAB, to run the following command:

```
try, someFunction('path/to/files', 'algorithm'), exit(); catch ME, warning(ME.message), exit(); end
```

For this, I generate the following command to handle ssh, executing matlab and run the above command:

```
C:\plink.exe user@server -pw ****** "matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -noawt -r 'try, someFunction('path/to/files', 'algorithm'), exit(); catch ME, warning(ME.message), exit(); end'
```

Running the above command, I get the following error in MATLAB:

```
Warning: Undefined function or variable 'path/to/files'.
```

As it turns out, in matlab, the command is constructed like following:

```
someFunction(path/to/files, algorithm)
```

which is without "single quotes": thank you, plink :( .

Can you please help to generate the correct command? or if there is already a question asked with similar problem, I would be thankful to direct me to it.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you @martin for the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's not Plink fault. It's how Windows command-line interpreter works.*

*Adding [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) and [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tags, so that you may get answers from experts on the field.*

---

Anyway, I can see two solutions:

- Put your command to a file like:

  ```
  matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -noawt -r "try, someFunction('path/to/files', 'algorithm'), exit(); catch ME, warning(ME.message), exit(); end"
  ```

  And use the file (`command.txt`) with Plink like:

  ```
  C:\plink.exe user@server -pw ****** -m command.txt
  ```
- If you do not want to use a separate file for the command, this should work too:

  ```
  echo matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -noawt -r "try, someFunction('path/to/files', 'algorithm'), exit(); catch ME, warning(ME.message), exit(); end" | C:\plink.exe user@server -pw ****** -T
  ```

  *(Note the `-T` switch).*

Comment: Thank you to the power of 10000000000000! I used the second solution of yours, using the -T switch.